# Error while checking balance using web3 API

Tags: ethereum, web3js, truffle

I am setting up an Ethereum environment in macOS following this link https://medium.com/coinmonks/setting-up-ethereum-development-environment-on-macos-22c96a136ac4 .
while checking the balance of the account by,

```
truffle(develop)> web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0x0ac4d68c2c34a3f1324439bff3c119f4ef675a72'),'ether').toNumber()
```

I get the following errors;

```
Thrown:
evalmachine.<anonymous>:0


web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0x0ac4d68c2c34a3f1324439bff3c119f4ef675a72'),'ether').toNumber()
 ^



TypeError: web3.fromWei is not a function
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:6
at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:279:15)
at Script.runInContext (vm.js:134:14)
at runScript (/Users/jigmewangmo/Documents/MSIT/BlockChain/EthereumWorkspace/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:251:1)
at Console.interpret (/Users/jigmewangmo/Documents/MSIT/BlockChain/EthereumWorkspace/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:266:1)
at bound (domain.js:420:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:433:12)
at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:700:10)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:209:13)
at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
```

Any idea why? I looked for resources online but confused as a suggested solution still gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided source is probably outdated. Check the `web3` version used and look up corresponding docs for `fromWei`.

For `web3` version [1.2.0](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#fromwei) use:

```
web3.utils.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0x0ac4d68c2c34a3f1324439bff3c119f4ef675a72'),'ether').toNumber()
```